# Python Programming Blank Output

Tags: python

```
while True:
    num=raw_input("Please enter a number.")
    if (num == 1):
        print "Sunday"
    elif (num==2):
        print "Monday"
    elif (num==3):
        print "Tuesday"
    elif (num==4):
        print "Wednesday"
    elif (num==5):
        print "Thursday"
    elif (num==6):
        print "Friday"
    elif (num==7):
        print "Saturday"
    else:
        print "Invalid Choice!"

    option = raw_input("Would you like to continue playing?")
    if (option=="yes"):
        continue
    elif (option=="no"):
        break
```

This my code. When I run it for some reason the output for the first part (The day's of the week) come up as the "else" option which is "Invalid Choice". And when I removed the else statement, the output was just blank. Slightly confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: Note that I fixed your indentation.

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input` will return the input as `str`. You have to convert it to `int` if you want to use it as a conditional for the `if` statements.

```
num=int(raw_input("Please enter a number."))
```

Note that if the user doesn't input a number, this will raise an error.

Comment: For validating inputs using Python take a look at: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

When you're building the program, I'd recommend you add more information to your "Invalid choice!" responses. For example:

```
print("You entered `{entry}` ({entry_type}), which is an invalid choice!".format(entry=num, entry_type=type(num)))
```

would have told you

> You entered `3` (<class 'str'>), which is an invalid choice!

which might suggest you either need to be comparing to strings, or casting your input to an integer.